# Incorrect ClassPath, after building Spring Boot API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, microservices

I am suffering from a small issue related to my Spring Boot Microservice, I recently moved my main.java file (which contains the main method), to a separate package, however this was causing problems so I had to revert it back to the original place , when I first created my project.

This is the error on my stack trace

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$RepositoryAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:111)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(boolean)'

The method's class, org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Engineering/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-dao/1.2.9/6f90baf86fc833cac3c677a8f35d3333ed86baea/spring-dao-1.2.9.jar!/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/Engineering/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.3.9-SNAPSHOT/d8f8af631e6429037c39f756fe2279f50c636844/spring-tx-5.3.9-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource: file:/C:/Users/Engineering/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-dao/1.2.9/6f90baf86fc833cac3c677a8f35d3333ed86baea/spring-dao-1.2.9.jar
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource: file:/C:/Users/Engineering/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-dao/1.2.9/6f90baf86fc833cac3c677a8f35d3333ed86baea/spring-dao-1.2.9.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**This is what I initially did**

I initially created a new folder in my main directory called Run, and placed my DemoApplication, the class that contains the main method. However this caused problems since it was not able to detect my controllers, (calling my endpoints gave a 404 not found error).

So I decided to delete the Run Package and put the DemoApplication class, by itself in the src->main folder.

**File Structure Currently**

[FileStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsg0V.png)

Before this, DemoApplication was placed in a package called Run.

Finally this is my build.gradle.

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.9-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudGcpVersion', "2.0.3")
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-hibernate
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-hibernate', version: '1.2.9'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    compile 'com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.3.0'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${springCloudGcpVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And my **DemoApplication.java** class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo","com.example.demo.Controllers","com.example.demo.model","com.example.demo.Services","com.example.demo.Respository"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.Respository")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You explicitly added a dependency that is _14 years old_. It's been replaced, and you can probably just delete it and rely on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: Apologies, but which dependency is this?

Comment: Thank you I have solved the problem, please repost your comment as an answer and I will mark it